# How to get the status of 'need to be restarted' of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, reboot

I need to get the status of the below restart-wanted icon as in the snapshot from command-line; so that I can make Windows 7 keep restarted until no such restart requirement still exists.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

### Option 1

1. Type `regedit` in Dialog Box(press [image] + <kbd>R</kbd>) or Start Menu search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It'll open Registry Editor.
2. go to following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows`.
3. Create a new key under **`Windows`** key and set its name to **`WindowsUpdate`**.
4. Create another new key under **`WindowsUpdate`** key and set its name to **AU**.
5. So the final key path would be: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU`.
6. Now select **AU** key and in right-side pane create a new **DWORD** named **`NoAUAsDefaultShutdownOption`** and set its value to **`0`**.

---

### Option 2

1. Open the *Group Police Editor*, press ([image] + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type `gpedit.msc`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Navigate to: `Computer Configuration` - `Adminstrative Templates` - `Components of Windows` - `Windows Update`.
3. **Disable** the first option, `Do not display Install Updates and Shutdown option.....`.
4. Look the image bellow.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you! Though I want to read the status not to remove it.

Comment: @NamG.VU What is said in this response is the reverse process of what is written [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-install-windows-updates-and-shut-down-option-in-windows-start-menu/).